# DBMS_ALERT.WAITANY hangs some time

Tags: plsql

I have a job, which will submit n other jobs. I have setup my pl/sql procedure to register for the n jobs using dbms_alert.register. Each of these jobs will send a dbms_alert.signal. I have issued a commit immediatly after the signal.

But sometime it hangs on servers processing them. Below is code snippet for the same. All alerts/jobs does either update or insert in different tables. They might have getting data/records using select query for same or different tables. Can anybody find what could cause this hang issue on server.

```
FUNCTION GenBociCltStm  RETURN NUMBER
            .......
            .........
             .......
        -- The following can be executed in any order (and in parallel)
        dbms_alert.register('CltMstAlert');
        dbms_alert.register('TrdPstAlert');
        dbms_alert.register('TrdLegAllAlert');
        dbms_alert.register('CrpActPstAlert');
        dbms_alert.register('SttPstAlert');
        dbms_alert.register('StkMovAlert');
        dbms_alert.register('StkHldAlert');
        dbms_alert.register('IntAlert');
        dbms_alert.register('TermLoanAlert');

        dbms_job.submit ( l_job,
                            ' BEGIN 
                PkgBociCltStmGen.GenBociCltStmCltMst; 
                exception when others then 
                    NULL;
                  END;
               dbms_alert.signal(''CltMstAlert'', ''GenBociCltStmCltMst Complete''); commit;',
               SYSDATE
               );

        dbms_job.submit ( l_job,
                            ' BEGIN 
                PkgBociCltStmGen.GenBociCltStmTrdPst; 
                exception when others then 
                    NULL;
                  END;
               dbms_alert.signal(''TrdPstAlert'', ''GenBociCltStmTrdPst Complete''); commit;',
               SYSDATE
               );

        dbms_job.submit ( l_job,
                            ' BEGIN 
                PkgBociCltStmGen.GenBociCltStmTrdLegAll; 
                exception when others then 
                    NULL;
                  END;
               dbms_alert.signal(''TrdLegAllAlert'', ''GenBociCltStmTrdLegAll Complete''); commit;',
               SYSDATE
               );

        dbms_job.submit ( l_job,
                            ' BEGIN 
                PkgBociCltStmGen.GenBociCltStmCrpActPst; 
                exception when others then 
                    NULL;
                  END;
               dbms_alert.signal(''CrpActPstAlert'', ''GenBociCltStmCrpActPst Complete''); commit;',
               SYSDATE
               );

        dbms_job.submit ( l_job,
                            ' BEGIN 
                PkgBociCltStmGen.GenBociCltStmSttPst; 
                exception when others then 
                    NULL;
                  END;
               dbms_alert.signal(''SttPstAlert'', ''GenBociCltStmSttPst Complete''); commit;',
               SYSDATE
               );

        dbms_job.submit ( l_job,
                            ' BEGIN 
                PkgBociCltStmGen.GenBociCltStmStkMov; 
                exception when others then 
                    NULL;
                  END;
               dbms_alert.signal(''StkMovAlert'', ''GenBociCltStmStkMov Complete''); commit;',
               SYSDATE
               );

        dbms_job.submit ( l_job,
                            ' BEGIN 
                PkgBociCltStmGen.GenBociCltStmStkHld; 
                exception when others then 
                    NULL;
                  END;
               dbms_alert.signal(''StkHldAlert'', ''GenBociCltStmStkHld Complete''); commit;',
               SYSDATE
               );

        dbms_job.submit ( l_job,
                            ' BEGIN 
                PkgBociCltStmGen.GenBociCltStmInt; 
                exception when others then 
                    NULL;
                  END;
               dbms_alert.signal(''IntAlert'', ''GenBociCltStmInt Complete''); commit;',
               SYSDATE
               );

    dbms_job.submit ( l_job,
                            ' BEGIN 
                PkgBociCltStmGen.GenBociCltStmTrmLon; 
                exception when others then 
                    NULL;
                  END;
                    dbms_alert.signal(''TermLoanAlert'', ''GenBociCltStmTrmLon Complete''); commit;',
                            SYSDATE
                            );
        commit;
         ......
         ......
         ......

        LOOP
            DBMS_ALERT.WAITANY(l_name, l_msg, l_status,6000);

            IF g_debug THEN
                SP_DEBUGLOG('===> alert '|| l_name,FALSE);
            END IF;

            l_counter := l_counter - 1;
            IF l_counter = 0 THEN
                EXIT;
            END IF;
        END LOOP;
```

Any suggestion will be highly appreciated!!

Comment: When you say it hangs, do you mean it fails to respond to the signal as expected? It is supposed to "hang". I think a simplified test case and some formatting will get you better answers, though.

Comment: Basically we call this package from our C++ code. When it hangs it never return back to C++ code. That is how it hangs